# Bitwise XOR in C using 64bit instead of 8bits

Tags: c, 64-bit, bit-manipulation, bitwise-xor

I consider how to make efficient **XORing** of **2 bytes arrays**. 
I have this bytes arrays defined as `unsigned char *`
I think that **XORing** them as `uint64_t` will be much faster. Is it true? 
How efficiently convert `unsigned char *` to this `uint64_t *` preferably **inside the XORing loop**? How to make padding of last bytes if **length** of the bytes array **% 8 isn't 0**?

Here is my current code that XORs bytes array, but each byte (unsigned char) separately:

```
unsigned char *bitwise_xor(const unsigned char *A_Bytes_Array, const unsigned char *B_Bytes_Array, const size_t length) {

    unsigned char *XOR_Bytes_Array;

    // allocate XORed bytes array
    XOR_Bytes_Array = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * length);

    // perform bitwise XOR operation on bytes arrays A and B
    for(int i=0; i < length; i++)
        XOR_Bytes_Array[i] = (unsigned char)(A_Bytes_Array[i] ^ B_Bytes_Array[i]);

    return XOR_Bytes_Array;
}
```

Ok, in the meantime I have tried to do it this way. My bytes_array are rather large (rgba bitmaps 4*1440*900?).

```
static uint64_t next64bitsFromBytesArray(const unsigned char *bytesArray, const int i) {

    uint64_t next64bits = (uint64_t) bytesArray[i+7] | ((uint64_t) bytesArray[i+6] << 8) | ((uint64_t) bytesArray[i+5] << 16) | ((uint64_t) bytesArray[i+4] << 24) | ((uint64_t) bytesArray[i+3] << 32) | ((uint64_t) bytesArray[i+2] << 40) | ((uint64_t) bytesArray[i+1] << 48) | ((uint64_t)bytesArray[i] << 56);
    return next64bits;
}

unsigned char *bitwise_xor64(const unsigned char *A_Bytes_Array, const unsigned char *B_Bytes_Array, const size_t length) {

    unsigned char *XOR_Bytes_Array;

    // allocate XORed bytes array
    XOR_Bytes_Array = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * length);

    // perform bitwise XOR operation on bytes arrays A and B using uint64_t
    for(int i=0; i<length; i+=8) {

        uint64_t A_Bytes = next64bitsFromBytesArray(A_Bytes_Array, i);
        uint64_t B_Bytes = next64bitsFromBytesArray(B_Bytes_Array, i);
        uint64_t XOR_Bytes = A_Bytes ^ B_Bytes;
        memcpy(XOR_Bytes_Array + i, &XOR_Bytes, 8);
    }

    return XOR_Bytes_Array; 
}
```

UPDATE: (2nd approach to this problem)

```
unsigned char *bitwise_xor64(const unsigned char *A_Bytes_Array, const unsigned char *B_Bytes_Array, const size_t length) {

    const uint64_t *aBytes = (const uint64_t *) A_Bytes_Array;
    const uint64_t *bBytes = (const uint64_t *) B_Bytes_Array;

    unsigned char *xorBytes = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*length);

    for(int i = 0, j=0; i < length; i +=8) {
            uint64_t aXORbBytes = aBytes[j] ^ bBytes[j];
            //printf("a XOR b = 0x%" PRIx64 "\n", aXORbBytes);
            memcpy(xorBytes + i, &aXORbBytes, 8);
            j++;
    }

    return xorBytes;
}
```

Comment: It's probably a bit faster, did you check ? How long are your arrays ? `malloc` is slow, so if your arrays are short, it won't make any difference. Padding if the length is not a multiple of 8 is almost trivial, show what you have tried.

Comment: Why should it be faster? Just open debugger and look at assembly code to check if there's difference in machine code.

Comment: @rlib Of course it is going to be faster if the specific CPU supports 64 bit XOR. 1 instruction instead of 8.

Comment: "I think that XORing them as uint64_t will be much faster": measure it and find out for certain.

Comment: I am sending this XORed data via socket it seems that now I can send in 30 sec about 77 images instead of 57 images. But they seems to be broken.

Comment: @Lundin The 64-bit XOR itself may be faster than eight 8-bit XOR instructions.  But the function `next64bitsFromBytesArray()` looks to me like it's going to be a *lot* slower than simply doing eight 8-bit XOR instructions.  8 array dereferences, 7 bit shifts, and 7 OR calculations and the overhead of a the function call, just to save 7 XOR calculations?  Maybe a good optimizing compiler can address some of that, but I'm doubtful.

Comment: So my question was how to make it efficiently ?

Comment: If the compiler notices the pattern and merges that stuff into a single 64bit load, it'll be fine. Of course, you could also explicitly tell it to do that.

Comment: Intereseting. I tried this and got 5.5x faster on my system (the code indicates it is 8x faster but it decays with caching/page faults etc.). However I doubt very much that this part of your code is slowing you down. Your byte arrays aren't very large considering modern computers. Mine does 64bit XOR of 100MB in a vritual machine in 0.2 seconds...

Comment: what about 2 approach? why it doesn't work correctly?

Comment: Ok i find error in 2nd approach, not it seems to work faster, and correct, as image in first approach was wrong.

Comment: also, if you're going for speed, avoid using dynamic memory and set some max size for your buffer then allocate it on your stack, memcpy() and malloc() all have overhead that you simply can avoid if you'd eliminate usage of dynamic memory

Comment: @Lundin: There are plenty of machines with non-8-bit chars.

Comment: @rlib "Plenty" is quite an exaggeration. There exist(ed) a few oddball DSPs and some 4 bit computers that were very unsuitable for high-level languages to begin with. Portability to wildly exotic, mildly retarded architectures shouldn't need to be a concern for 99.99% of all programmers.

Comment: Calling `memcpy` is probably not the fastest option for copying 8 bytes.

Comment: but how can I copy it in different way?

Comment: `memcpy(XOR_Bytes_Array + i, &XOR_Bytes, 8);` ->  `*((uint64_t*)(XOR_Bytes_Array + i)) = XOR_Bytes;`

Comment: Yeah it seems to be half faster with this instead of memcpy.  I'm using execution time with `clock_t`

Answer (score 1):

So I did an experiment:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#ifndef TYPE
#define TYPE uint64_t
#endif

TYPE *
xor(const void *va, const void *vb, size_t l)
{
        const TYPE *a = va;
        const TYPE *b = vb;
        TYPE *r = malloc(l);
        size_t i;

        for (i = 0; i < l / sizeof(TYPE); i++) {
                *r++ = *a++ ^ *b++;
        }
        return r;
}
```

Compiled both for `uint64_t` and `uint8_t` with clang with basic optimizations. In both cases the compiler vectorized the hell out of this. The difference was that the uint8_t version had code to handle when `l` wasn't a multiple of 8. So if we add code to handle the size not being a multiple of 8, you'll probably end up with equivalent generated code. Also, the 64 bit version unrolled the loop a few times and had code to handle that, so for big enough arrays you might gain a few percent here. On the other hand, on big enough arrays you'll be memory-bound and the xor operation won't matter a bit.

Are you sure your compiler won't deal with this? This is a kind of micro-optimization that makes sense only when you're measuring things and then you wouldn't need to ask which one is faster, you'd know.

Comment: On my laptop I see the difference, while using uint64_t, I am copying 80-90 images via socket, while using uint8_t I am copying 55-65 images. It seems to do much better